# Por que muitos portugueses usam "à" ao expressar tempo passado?

Tags: ortografia, gramática, português-europeu

Vários portugueses parecem usar muito "à" quando no Brasil quem sabe escrever corretamente usa o "há" para expressar tempo passado. Existe algum motivo desta diferença? É oficial? Ou também é erro dos portugueses? Ou ainda muitos brasileiros aprenderam errado?

Exemplo:

> Estou esperando à 2 horas

Comment: Você está perguntando uma coisa no título, mas uma outra no corpo da questão. No próprio corpo da sua pergunta você já diz que o correto é "há", respondendo a pergunta do título. Sugiro tentar encontrar um título melhor, tal como **Por que muitos portugueses usam "à" ao expressar tempo passado?**

Comment: Eu cá vejo muitos brasileiros escrever "à" em vez de "a".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Em português, mesmo na variante europeia, é completamente errado escrever a contração "à" em vez da forma verbal "há", em situações que se refiram a tempo passado: deve ser, por exemplo, "há duas semanas" e não "à duas semanas". A contração do artigo definido feminino com a proposição "a" utiliza-se em frases como "fui à feira".

Comment: Sim, é errado em qualquer variante. Mas o curioso é que esse erro parece ser mais frequente entre portugueses do que entre brasileiros.

Comment: @bfavaretto É verdade. Em Portugal este erro, com a frequência atual, tem cerca de 20 anos, no máximo.

Comment: @bfavaretto Isto deve-se à pronúncia ser igual

Comment: @bfavaretto A pronúncia sempre foi igual, mas há cerca de 30 a 60 anos quase ninguém cometia este erro.

Comment: Interessante que isso seja um sinônimo recente. Será que a culpa é da internet? :P

Comment: @bfavaretto a culpa não é da internet é dos teclados. Eu se escrever a mão com caneta não dou esse erro. Ao escrever no teclado acontece-me com frequência.

Comment: @AméricoTavares o problema veio com as maquinas de escrever e com os teclados de computador.

Comment: Não compreendo como é que os teclados possam ser culpados. Por outro lado, lembrem-se que há 30 anos  pouca gente escrevia, e nós observávamos sobretudo a escrita de profissionais nos jornais (ou algum de vocês é professor?) e agora toda a gente escreve em sites como este. Temos muito mais oportunidade de observar os erros dos outros.

Comment: Seria interessante citar também o caso correto de "a duas semanas atrás" por exemplo?

Comment: Sim, concordo com @Jacinto  O que ocorre é que com o surgimento da Internet, das redes sociais, do whatsapp, das mensagens de texto no celular, passamos a observar a escrita de quem antes não escrevia, apenas falava.  E na língua falada não há como perceber um erro de ortografia quando os sons são idênticos.  No Brasil também muita gente escreve "a uma semana" ou "à uma semana" e isso não é exclusividade dos Portugueses.  Entrem no Facebook e vejam como nós, brasileiros, escrevemos.

Answer (score 10):

Vi esse fenômeno ocorrer muitas vezes no Stack Overflow em Português, e de fato parece ser comum os portugueses utilizarem "à" incorretamente no lugar de "há". Eu tenho uma hipótese, mas como sou brasileiro gostaria de ouvir uma confirmação dos portugueses.

[É sabido](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/crase-pronuncia/15817) que em Portugal há uma distinção clara de pronúncia entre "a aberto" e "a fechado". O "a" craseado tem som aberto, enquanto o artigo "a" sozinho tem som fechado. O "há", do verbo *haver* também tem som aberto, e seu suponho que venha daí a confusão com o "à", já que ambos têm a mesma sonoridade.

Comment: Essa parece ser a fonte da confusão, de fato

Comment: O que eu acho curioso é isto correr com pessoas de bom nível cultural. No Brasil só costuma ocorrer com pessoas pouco instruídas.

Comment: É mesmo isso bfavaretto, mas o correto é **há**.

Comment: @bigown isso acontece ao escrever rápido. Como a sonoridade é a mesma o que sai sem pensar é **à** e às vezes sem acento...

Comment: Mas, @someonewithpc e bafavaretto, _à_ e _há_ são homófonos também no Brasil, portanto isso só por si não desculpa os portugueses serem mais trapalhões que os brasileiros. Ou será que nas escolas brasileiras se insiste muito mais nessas coisas por causa de ser necessário distinguir na escrita _a_ de _à_, que imagino que seja uma bela dor de cabeça para eles?

Comment: @Jacinto _A_ e _há_ são homófonos no Brasil? Talvez seja por isso; isto não significa que "os portugueses sejam mais trapalhões" já que é comum confundir _mas_ com _mais_ no Brasil,  o que nunca aconteceria em Portugal.

Comment: @Jacinto Sim, existe esse problema no Brasil, e nós somos até mais trapalhões, já que aqui *a*, *à* e *há*  são homófonos. Em Portugal *me parece* que o problema fica restrito a  *à* e *há*,

Comment: Pelos vistos não me expliquei bem. Vou tentar de novo. Várias pessoas aqui observaram que o erro do tipo _à dois anos_ é mais comum entre portugueses que brasileiros. bfavaretto, apoiado por @someonewithpc, sugere que é por _à_ e _há_ serem homófonos. E a minha observação é: eles são homófonos quer em Portugal quer no Brasil, portanto essa homofonia só por si não explica o facto de os portugueses terem mais tendência do que os brasileiros  a escrever _à X anos_. Tem que haver outra explicação. Sugeri que talvez nas escolas brasileiras se insistisse mais nestas coisas.

Answer (score 6):

A homofonia entre *à* e *há* sem dúvida que contribui para o erro. E além disso, creio que, para quem nunca viu a expressão escrita, ao ouvir *há dois anos* não se apercebe que a primeira palavra é uma forma do verbo haver, até por que não é nada óbvio.

Eu era já adulto quando dei comigo a pensar se era *à dois anos* ou *há dois anos*. Imagino que nunca tivesse lido aquela construção, afinal é bastante mais comum na linguagem falada do que na escrita, ou que tivesse lido e não tivesse prestado atenção. Fosse o que fosse, o que é certo é que até aí eu tinha usado a construção como uma expressão idiomática, sem nunca ter pensado no significado da primeira palavrinha isoladamente.

Claro que depois descobri ou cheguei à conclusão que era *há dois anos: existem dois anos*. Mas na verdade, há algo de idiomático na expressão. Por que razão se diz *há dois anos visitei a Polónia*? A concordância de número exigiria *hão dois anos visitei a Polónia*. Substituindo o *há* por *existe* evidencia ainda outro problema: *existe dois anos visitei a Polónia*. Não deveria ser *existem dois anos desde que visitei a Polónia*? Não admira que não salte à vista, ou ao ouvido neste caso, a primeira palavrinha ser uma forma do verbo haver.

Provavelmente quem escreve *à dois anos* nem toma consciência que *à* é a contração da preposição com o artigo. Se tomassem, teriam que escrever *aos dois anos* ou talvez *a dois anos* (se nós dizemos *daqui a dois anos*...) e na distinção entre *a* e *à* os portugueses até se safam. Portanto imagino que quem faz o erro pense que aquele *à* tem outro significado qualquer que só se aplica naquela construção. Seria interessante fazer um inquérito.

Entretanto pesquisei no Google a frequência do erro em Portugal e no Brasil. Os resultados estão na tabela abaixo.

### Resultados do Google Search

```
                                                        Percentagem do total
Brasil                      há   ha   à    a   á        há + ha    à + a + á
Esperando [] muito tempo    317  60  130  286  31         52%         48%
Esperando [] horas          124  19   29  114  29         45%         55%

Portugal
[] bué de/da tempo          101  31   65   63  52         42%         58%
Espera [] muito tempo       119  16   42   28   2         65%         35%
Espera [] imenso tempo       45   3   17   12   6         58%         42%
Espera [] horas              40   0    6    2   5         75%         25%
```

Globalmente parece que brasileiros e portugueses têm mais ou menos a mesma propensão a errar. Em Portugal parece haver um padrão curioso. *Bué de* ou *bué da* (o *da* é aqui usado independentemente do género da palavra seguinte), significando ‘grande quantidade de, muito’, é usado praticamente só por malta jovem; e é associado a esta expressão que a frequência relativa do erro é maior. Não creio que os jovens escrevam pior que os adultos. O que acontece é que todos os jovens escrevem na net; enquanto entre os mais velhos, são predominantemente os mais instruídos. E não encontrei nenhum *esperando há/à/etc. **imenso** tempo* no Brasil!

Comment: Parece-me que o que te falhou foi o modelo mental correto para "há dois anos". Talvez falta de exposição ao popular "ele há dois anos que já cá estou", ao (comum na escrita, mas não tanto na oralidade) "havia dois anos que não se viam" ou à construção completamente análoga "faz/faziam dois anos"

Comment: Sem dúvida que eu não tinha o modelo correto. E na oralidade há uma porção de modelos errados que dão o resultado correto. Eu ainda ouvi a pessoas mais velhas esse _ele_ fictício popular, em expressões como "ele há coisas (que vá lá uma pessoa enteder)" ou para enumerar com ênfase uma lista anormalmente longa, como "esta casa parece um restaurante: ele é feijoada, ele coelho, ele é peixe frito..."

Comment: Jacinto eu erro muito a escrever por causa de escrever no teclado, a escrever a mão nunca erro. Entende? É aquele automático do teclado, vai tudo corrido a "a" quando quero dizer "a", "à" ou "há". As vezes vai tudo corrido a "à".

Comment: Sim, entendo. É mais fácil pôr o acento ao escrever à mão que num teclado, especialmente o grave, que exige carregar em duas teclas. Ainda por cima a maioria de nós nunca aprendeu datilografia, escrever com os dedos todos sem olhar para o teclado. Mas isso é também por não te preocupares em rever o que escreveste.

Comment: Compreendo acentos. Omitir o h já me faz mais confusão.

Comment: Não se diz “Hão dois anos” porque o haver é impessoal, então fica sempre há. **Há vários exemplos** dessa impessoalidade do verbo haver. No Brasil às vezes se diz “Tem dois anos...”, o que expõe a característica verbal dessa expressão. Em compensação, muitas pessoas nem se dão conta de usar **Havia** no passado (como em “Aquilo já estava pronto havia três meses”), o que indica que as pessoas entendem esse “há” como se fosse uma preposição.

Comment: No Brasil nunca ouvi “ele há”, mas estudando francês logo cedo aprendemos a expressão “il y a”, que corresponde ao nosso simples “há”, tanto no sentido de existir, quanto no sentido de tempo passado. Por comparação com outras línguas também podemos constatar que “hás vezes” seria uma coisa muito peculiar, já que em espanhol se diz “a veces” (sem artigo) e em francês “parfois”.

Comment: Tens razão no _hão dois anos_, até porque _dois anos_ é o objeto (ou complemento ou o raio que o parta)  e o verbo haver concorda com o sujeito e não com o objeto. Entusiasmei-me.

Comment: @marcus , _hás vezes_ seria peculiar, mas não de todo incompreensível,  e o que não faltam na nossa língua são expressões peculiares. Vê o exemplo de _ter a ver_.