# "Há" será sempre usado para passado e "a" para futuro?

Tags: português-brasileiro, gramática

Já é a segunda vez que sou corrigida por pessoas inteligentes nessa questão, porém, sempre que pesquiso, me deparo com a regra de "há" usado para se referir a tempos passados, e "a", para futuro.
Por exemplo, em "Farei o que pediu daqui a pouco", se usa o "a" ao invés de "há", pois se trata de um tempo futuro, enquanto em "Há muito tempo, fiz o que pediu" se usa "há", pois se refere a algo que já foi feito.

A última situação em que me chamaram atenção, foi uma transcrição em que a mulher dizia assim:

> "Eu tenho 6 anos de formada e passei a atender em consultório há, aproximadamente, 5 anos atrás".

Afinal, existe exceção para o uso de uma ou de outra, que eu não esteja sabendo?

Obrigada!

Comment: Se não te for incômodo, em que site, se tiver sido um site, encontraste essa regra?

Comment: _Há_ é uma forma do verbo _haver_, que é aqui sinónimo de _fazer_: _não o vejo há/faz 3 anos_, _não o tinha visto havia/fazia 3 anos_, _nessa altura, não o terei visto haverá/fará 3 anos_. Não percebo a relação com  _a_.  Tens algum exemplo?

Comment: Isso do *a* em relação ao futuro, estás a pensar em algo como, *volto de hoje a três semanas*? Secundando o Artefacto, seria útil um exemplo.

Comment: "há aproximadamente cinco anos" dispensa o uso de "atrás".

Comment: Isso mesmo, Jacinto. Seria nesse sentido.
Ex: farei o que pediu daqui a pouco

Comment: @Schilive não é um site específico, pesquisei no Google. Em qualquer site de gramática se encontra essa regra...

Comment: @FláviadeMarcos, engraçado: nunca ouvi nem falar dessa regra. A minha professora ensinou doutra forma. Ela ensinou que "há" pode se trocar por "tem"; ex.: "eu nasci há dez anos", "eu nasci tem dez anos"; se não funcionar "tem", o correto é "a"; ex.: "tem dez anos, matei um homem" não funciona — funciona, mas é estranha —, então o correto é "a dez anos eu matei um homem". O mesmo se aplicaria a "eu nasci tem dez mil anos atrás": a frase funciona e transmite a mesma coisa, mas fica estranha, então o correto seria "eu nasci a dez mil anos atrás".Claro, eu posso estar errado.

Comment: @Schilive, "eu nasci há dez mil anos* pode ser esquisito para ti, mas é corretíssimo; "eu nasci a dez mil anos" é que é errado. Vê a minha resposta.

Comment: Flávia, a tua pergunta ficaria mais clara se incorporasses nela o esclarecimento que me prestaste aqui nos comentários. Poderias incluir o exemplo que deste, "farei o que pediu daqui a pouco". Basta clicar em "edit", à esquerda abaixo da pergunta, e fazer as alterações que quiseres. Outra coisa, quando respondes a alguém nos comentários, escreve "@" antes do nome para a pessoa ser notificada. Por exemplo,  @Flávia (mesmo só por exemplo, porque como és autora do post, não é preciso o @ para seres notificada)..

Comment: @Schilive estranho ter aprendido dessa forma, pois deixa uma brecha muito grande a depender da pessoa que está usando. Quando fiquei em dúvida, me deparei com essa regra de presente x passado e, desde então, tenho usado somente dessa forma. Acho mais fácil de memorizar.

Comment: @Jacinto Grata pela resposta, foi muito útil! Vou editar o post.

Answer (score 4):

Essa regra está basicamente correta. Exemplo: *eu cheguei **há** dez minutos, e o João vai chegar daqui **a** cinco minutos*.

### Passado: *cheguei há dez minutos*

Como já explicado nos comentários, esse *há* do passado é do verbo *haver*. *Haver* significa ’existir’, portanto é como se disséssemos *cheguei, existem dez minutos* / *existem dez minutos desde que cheguei*. É claro que ninguém diz *existem dez minutos*; o que se diz frequentemente em vez de *há* é *faz: faz dez minutos que cheguei*.

Este uso de *há* gera muita confusão, e vê-se muita gente escrever *à* ou mesmo *a*  em vez de *há* (vê [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/47/por-que-muitos-portugueses-usam-%C3%A0-ao-expressar-tempo-passado?rq=1)) possivelmente porque na linguagem oral, onde não se vê o h, não reconhecem a palavra como forma do verbo haver. Uma boa maneira de distinguir é precisamente ver se é possível substituir por *faz*:

> [Correto:] Cheguei faz dez minutos → Cheguei há dez minutos
>
> [Errado:] *Chegarei daqui faz cinco minutos → [Correto:] Chegarei daqui a cinco minutos

Quando falamos de um tempo anterior a um outro tempo já no passado, deve ser *havia:*

> Despediram-no o ano passado; trabalhava lá havia vinte anos
>
> Quando lá cheguei, ele já estava à minha espera havia quinze minutos.

Mas é muito frequente ouvir pessoas dizerem neste tipo de frases *há* em vez de *havia*, possivelmente, novamente, por não se lembrarem que isto é tudo o verbo *haver*.

Os portugueses, pelo menos, complementam muito frequentemente este *há* com *atrás: há trinta anos atrás, ele ainda não era nascido*. Muitos educadores condenam isto, argumentado que a adição do *atrás* constitui um pleonasmo, porque *há* já indica o tempo passado. Mas aparentemente já há gramáticos que aceitam este *atrás*, argumentando consagração pelo uso. (Vê artigo de [Flavia Neves no Dicio](https://duvidas.dicio.com.br/ha-dez-anos-ou-ha-dez-anos-atras/).)

### Futuro: *Chegarei daqui a cinco minutos*

Este *a* é a preposição. As preposições são frequentemente complicadas, e o seu significado exato não é fácil de explicar, mas repara que neste caso o uso é sempre ***daqui a X tempo***. Isto é semelhante ao uso com distâncias físicas:

> Dobre à direita daqui **a** cem metros
>
> Daqui **a** São Paulo são 100 km
>
> Do Porto **a** Lisboa são 300 km

Nestes casos, a preposição *a* indica o limite de um movimento (tal como em *vou **a** São Paulo*; creio que este uso da preposição *a* não é muito comum no Brasil, mas é absolutamente corriqueiro em Portugal). Em *daqui **a** cinco minutos*, a preposição indica o limite de uma espécie de movimento no tempo.

Este *a* em rigor não se refere necessariamente ao futuro. Refere-se é a um tempo depois de um tempo de referência, podendo ambos estar no passado:

> Ontem, eram nove da manhã, o noivo ainda não chegara, e o casamento deveria começar **dali a dez minutos**

Aqui, o tempo de referência é ontem às 9h00, e há um outro tempo posterior, ontem às 9h10, sendo ambos os tempos no passado. Nestes casos, o *daqui* passa normalmente a *dali* ou *daí*.