# Já ouvi as seguintes duas formas :"há quanto tempo" e "a quanto tempo" ? É possível utilizar as duas situações para referir a orações passadas?

Tags: verbos, tempo-verbal

"há quanto tempo" e "a quanto tempo"? É possível utilizar as duas situações para referir a orações passadas?

Comment: Me desculpa mas as formas variantes ortográficas se dizem da mesma maneira. "há" e "a" se falam da mesma maneira. Há quanto tempo = Faz quanto tempo, forma interrogativa.  O "a" se refere ao futuro: https://www.normaculta.com.br/ha-ou-a-na-expressao-de-tempo/

Comment: CIMend, ouviste "a quanto tempo" referindo um momento passado? Podes dar um exemplo? Eu nunca ouvi. Ou queres dizer "**à** quanto tempo"? (Que está errado, mas na fala **à** não se distingue de **há**.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

resposta curta: não.

resposta longa: "a" serve para tempo futuro e "há" serve para tempo passado.

expressões em que usa-se o artigo "a":

> Daqui a quanto tempo sairemos?

> Daqui a duas semanas eles partirão para a Europa.

> Estamos a dois dias das eleições.

expressões em que usa-se o verbo haver conjugado na terceira pessoa do singular:

> Há quanto tempo você está aí?

> Há duas semanas eles partiram para a Europa.

> As eleições foram há dois dias.

Há um truque que me foi ensinado por minha saudosa professora de português, no que no Brasil chama-se de ensino fundamental, que me ajudou muito a fixar essa ideia, sempre que você estiver na duvida se deve usar "a" ou "há" tente substituir pelos verbos "ter" ou "fazer", se a frase ainda fizer sentido então o correto é o uso do "há", caso não faça sentido o correto é o uso do "a".

Usando como exemplo frases que já usei acima:

> Estamos a dois dias das eleições.

trocando por fazer: -estamos faz dois dias das eleições

trocando por ter: -estamos tem dois dias das eleições

nenhuma dessas frases têm sentido pois a eleição está no futuro, porém os verbos "ter" e "fazer" dão à frase sentido de algo que está no passado logo a frase fica mal formulada e confusa.

> Há quanto tempo você está aí?

trocando por fazer: -faz quanto tempo que você está aí?

trocando por ter: -tem quanto tempo que você está aí?

ainda que tivéramos que adicionar a conjunção "que" para unir as duas orações, você pode notar que ambas as frases estão coesas, portanto neste caso deve-se usar "há"

Comment: Interessante, eu nem tinha interpretado o "a quanto tempo" como o "daqui a X tempo". Há até já [esta pergunta sobre esse assunto](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/8154/h%c3%a1-ser%c3%a1-sempre-usado-para-passado-e-a-para-futuro). >>

Comment: Pergunto-me se o autor da pergunta não quiz dizer "à quanto tempo": "há" e "à" são homófonos", e há muita gente que escreve erradamente "à muito tempo" em vez de "há..."; na verdade também muitos escrevem "cheguei a 5 minutos", mas isso é duplo erro: 1º - "à" em vez de "há"; 2º - "a" em vez de "à", que muitos não põem acentos (em Portugal "a" e "há/à" não são homófonos); também há [uma pergunta sobre isso](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/47/por-que-muitos-portugueses-usam-%c3%a0-ao-expressar-tempo-passado).